# Stored Procedure ora-06550 and ora-00905

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, datagrip

I created this *stored procedure* in order to show the avg cases in a province.
When it gets a valid province (comparison with the PROVINCE table) as a parameter, the cont variable is raised.
When it is not raised cont=0 then -> exception.
If it is raised then -> go on with te procedure which should output me the line I wrote with the **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE** and it has to show the name of the province and the number of cases.
Anyway it doesn't work and I cannot comprehend why. I get ora-06550 and ora-00905.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Media_Casi_totali(Provincia IN PROVINCE.denominazione_provincia%TYPE)
> AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE
>         Media_dei_casi_totali COVID_PROVINCE.Totale_Casi%TYPE;
>         Cont INTEGER;
>         Provincia_Errata EXCEPTION;
>
>         BEGIN
>         select count(*| INT) Cont
>         from PROVINCE P INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA = CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
>         where p.denominazione_provincia=Provincia;
>         IF (cont=0) then
>             Raise Provincia_Errata;
>         ELSE
>             select ROUND(AVG(CP.TOTALE_CASI),3) INTO Media_dei_casi_totali
>             FROM PROVINCE P INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA=CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
>             WHERE P.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA=Provincia;
>             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Media dei casi totali' || 'relativi alla provincia di' || Provincia || ':' || Media_dei_casi_totali);
>             END IF;
>         EXCEPTION
>         WHEN Provincia_Errata THEN
>         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La Provincia selezionata non esiste');
>         END;
>     END Media_Casi_totali;
> ```

Comment: You declare variables above the `begin`. If you really want to start another block with `declare`, you need to end it as well as the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid syntax, here:

```
select count(*| INT) Cont
```

Should be

```
select count(*) into Cont
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Media_Casi_totali (
   Provincia  IN PROVINCE.denominazione_provincia%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      Media_dei_casi_totali  COVID_PROVINCE.Totale_Casi%TYPE;
      Cont                   INTEGER;
      Provincia_Errata       EXCEPTION;
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT (*)
        INTO Cont
        FROM PROVINCE P
             INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP
                ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA = CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
       WHERE p.denominazione_provincia = Provincia;

      IF (cont = 0)
      THEN
         RAISE Provincia_Errata;
      ELSE
         SELECT ROUND (AVG (CP.TOTALE_CASI), 3)
           INTO Media_dei_casi_totali
           FROM PROVINCE P
                INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP
                   ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA = CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
          WHERE P.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA = Provincia;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
               'Media dei casi totali'
            || 'relativi alla provincia di'
            || Provincia
            || ':'
            || Media_dei_casi_totali);
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN Provincia_Errata
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('La Provincia selezionata non esiste');
   END;
END Media_Casi_totali;
```

Comment: It compiles but when I do:
**begin
    Media_Casi_totali('Napoli');
end;**
I can see the right execution on the console but I'm not able to see any output.
I tried to insert a wrong province and it still compiles not giving me the exception.

Comment: If you can't see any output, did you `set serveroutput on`? If not, do so. Otherwise you won't see the result of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`

Comment: I tried but it is a SQL plus function and on datagrip I cannot use it

Comment: I don't know what "datagrip" is so I can't tell what exactly to do, but - it *should* have some option to display the output; maybe it is a button which enables it, or another tab, or ... I don't know what.

Comment: yes, I found a button that shows me the output buffer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would make it even simpler, of course after fixing the issue with the cont variable that is not well codified.

**Update** There was a missing end

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Media_Casi_totali(Provincia IN PROVINCE.denominazione_provincia%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        Media_dei_casi_totali COVID_PROVINCE.Totale_Casi%TYPE;
        Cont INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.enable(null);
        select count(*) into Cont
        from PROVINCE P INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA = CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
        where p.denominazione_provincia=Provincia;
        IF cont=0 then
            raise_application_error(-20001,'Error here - counter is 0');
        ELSE
            select ROUND(AVG(CP.TOTALE_CASI),3) INTO Media_dei_casi_totali
            FROM PROVINCE P INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA=CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
            WHERE P.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA=Provincia;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Media dei casi totali' || 'relativi alla provincia di' || Provincia || ':' || Media_dei_casi_totali);
            END IF;
    END;
EXCEPTION
        when others then raise;
 END Media_Casi_totali;
```

Then to run it

```
 SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
 SQL> EXEC Media_Casi_totali ( Provincia => xxxx );
```

I prefer to use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR because in your case is more addecuate, I belive. I would use exception if I have a pragma_exception_init associated to it to control an Oracle specific exception. In your case is a logical exception, you want to raise an error if the counter is 0.

Test case

```
SQL> create table province ( codice_provincia number , denominazione_provincia varchar2(100) );

Table created.
SQL> create table COVID_PROVINCE ( codice_provincia number , Totale_Casi number );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Media_Casi_totali(Provincia IN PROVINCE.denominazione_provincia%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        Media_dei_casi_totali COVID_PROVINCE.Totale_Casi%TYPE;
        Cont INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.enable(null);
        select count(*) into Cont
        from PROVINCE P INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA = CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
        where p.denominazione_provincia=Provincia;
        IF cont=0 then
            raise_application_error(-20001,'Error here - counter is 0');
        ELSE
            select ROUND(AVG(CP.TOTALE_CASI),3) INTO Media_dei_casi_totali
            FROM PROVINCE P INNER JOIN COVID_PROVINCE CP ON P.CODICE_PROVINCIA=CP.CODICE_PROVINCIA
            WHERE P.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA=Provincia;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Media dei casi totali' || 'relativi alla provincia di' || Provincia || ':' || Media_dei_casi_totali);
            END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        when others then raise;
    end;
 23  END Media_Casi_totali;
 24  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Regards

Comment: PLS-00103: Found symbol "end-of-file" instead of one of the slippers:
--( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
-- null pragma raise return select update while with
-- <un identificativo>
-- <un identificativo delimitato da virgolette>
-- <una bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch
-- lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit
-- forall merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query
-- json_object json_array

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I edited the answer and provide you a test example